# Factorial of a matrix: what could be the use of it?

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, factorial, matrix-calculus, applications

Recently on this site, the [question was raised](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1634488/264509) how we might define the factorial operation $\mathsf{A}!$ on a square matrix $\mathsf{A}$. The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1634551/264509), perhaps unsurprisingly, involves the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

What use might it be to take the factorial of a matrix?  Do any applications come to mind, or does this – for now* – seem to be restricted to the domain of recreational mathematics?

<sup>(*Until e.g. theoretical physics turns out to have a use for this, as happened with [Calabi–Yau manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold) and [superstring theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superstring_theory)...)</sup>

Comment: Perhaps it can be used to define the factorial of a quaternion? (That is, one would represent the quaternion by its matrix representation and find the factorial of that. It seems the final answer involves $\left(a\pm i\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2}\right)\!\!\matrix{\large!}\!$, which we know how to define.)

Comment: This is a bit speculative, but it is probably useful in probability theory. The factorial/gamma function is a pretty common component in random variable probability densities, (think poisson, gamma, beta distributions), and generalising univariate pdfs to multivariate pdfs often involves replacing the role of a single variable with a matrix. The matrix exponential shows up a lot in probability theory, so there might be some occurrences of the matrix factorial as well.

Answer (score 6):

I could find the following references that take the use of matrix factorial for a concrete applied context:

***Coherent Transform, Quantization and Poisson Geometry:*** In his [book](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Coherent_Transform_Quantization_and_Pois/5jGveNHXftgC)  Mikhail Vladimirovich Karasev uses for example the matrix factorial for hypersurfaces and twisted hypergeometric functions.

[image]

***Artificial Intelligence Algorithms and Applications:*** In this [conference proceeding](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Artificial_Intelligence_Algorithms_and_A/0DTnDwAAQBAJ) the Bayesian probability matrix factorial is used in the context of classification of imputation methods for missing traffic data.

***Fluid model:*** Mao, Wang and Tan deal in their [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12190-010-0467-7) (Journal of Applied Mathematics and Computing) with a fluid model driven by an $M/M/1$ queue with multiple exponential vacations and $N$-policy.

***Construction of coherent states for multi-level quantum systems:*** In [their paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/37/40/014/meta) "Vector coherent states with matrix moment problems" Thirulogasanthar and Hohouéto use matrix factorial in context of quantum physics.

***Algorithm Optimization***: Althought this is a more theoretic field of application, I would like to mention this matrix factorial use case as well. Vladica Andrejić, Alin Bostan and Milos Tatarevic present in their [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020019020301654) improved algorithms for computing the left factorial residues $!p=0!+1!+\ldots+(p−1)!\bmod{p}$. They confirm that there are no socialist primes $p$ with $5<p<2^{40}$. You may take a look into an [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09196) of this paper.

Answer (score 0):

The factorial has a straightforward interpretation in terms of automorphisms/permutations as the size of the set of automorphisms.

One possible generalization of matrices is the double category of spans.

So an automorphism $ R ! = R \leftrightarrow R $ over a span $A \leftarrow R \rightarrow B$ ought to be a reasonable generalization.

I usually find it easier to think in terms of profunctors or relations than spans.

The residual/internal hom of profunctors $(R/R)(a, b) = \forall x, R(x, a) \leftrightarrow R(x, b) $ is a kan extension. The kan extension of a functor with itself is the codensity monad. For profunctors and spans the automorphism ought to be a groupoid (a monad in the category of endospans equipped with inverses.)

The factorial is the size of the automorphism group of a set. The automorphism group ought to generalize to a "automorphism groupoid" of a span. I suspect permutation of a matrix ought to be a automorphism groupoid enriched in Vect but this confuses me.