# Why the circle of radius larger than $||A||$ can ensclose all the eigenvalues of A?

Tags: matrices

Trying to understand the answer of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634488/how-could-we-define-the-factorial-of-a-matrix) question, I took a hour to seek, some things I never learn in class, in the net like holomorphic functions et caetera, so now all is understandable for me, but not one things.

They say in the article [Matrix Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function#Cauchy_integral) that to enclose all the eigenvalues *one possibility to achieve this is to let $C$ be a circle around the origin with radius larger than $‖A‖$ for an arbitrary matrix norm $‖.‖$*

Can someone prove it ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $x$ such that $\|x\|=1$ be an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $c$, $\|A(x)\| =\mid c\mid \leq \|A\|$.