# Exponential of a specific matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

The matrix is

$$ A = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        4 & -2& \\
        3 & -1&\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

And I need to caluclate $\exp(At)$, where $t$ is real.

Not sure what I need to do after I multiply everything by $t$

please help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate ? There have been extensive discussions on matrix functions. See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634488/how-could-we-define-the-factorial-of-a-matrix/1980621#1980621, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128408/why-does-matrixfunction-with-sinc-return-this-error/128437#128437. See also the "Related" section.

Comment: Why $\&$ before $\backslash\backslash$ in the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

- Diagonalize $At$, which will give you $P$ such that $At=PDP^{-1}$.
- Remark that if $\exp(At)=P\exp(D)P^{-1}$.
- Since $D$ is diagonal, $\exp(D)$ is easy to calculate.

Comment: Actually, it is sufficient to diagonalize just $\mathbf A$, since for a scalar $t$, $t \mathbf A=t \mathbf P \mathbf D \mathbf {P^{-1}}=\mathbf P t \mathbf D \mathbf {P^{-1}}$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Laplace transform;
$$\exp(At)=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{ (sI-A)^{-1} \}.$$