# Defective Matrices Transforms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Defective Matrix:$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

I am unable to wrap my head around what kind of transforms yield defective matrices or matrices where geometric multiplicity is less than algebric multiplicity. A part that confuses me is the matrix is full rank yet we dont have a basis of eigenvectors possible. I want to know what kind of transforms are these as in projection, reflection or what? What are these transformations that have such a special property(explanations in 2D and 3D).

Here is an example of the type of explanation im looking for but I don't get WHY its true or what causes it:[Why are some linear transformations defective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287824/why-are-some-linear-transformations-defective) . How do I grok these transformations? It seems a bit un-natural to me.

Comment: You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/472915/81360) helpful

Comment: Another perspective: every matrix can be regarded as a direct sum of Jordan blocks, and every Jordan block can be thought of as a scaled [shear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping).