# Geometrically, what does it mean for a matrix to be degenerate? (i.e. have non-distinct eigenvalues)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to understand matrix operations as geometric transformations. For example, in the $2$x$2$ case, the matrix $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1  \\
    0 & 2  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$ produces a shear. However, this is also an upper triangular matrix, so the eigenvalues are on the diagonal, and are not distinct, i.e. both in this case are $2$. I understand what a shear looks like geometrically, but more generally, how do I "spot" a degenerate matrix transformation? What, geometrically, would it mean for a matrix transformation to be degenerate?

Comment: Note that your matrix has a more interesting property than simply having duplicate eigenvalues: it is also [defective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix), that is, it does not have a complete set of eigenvectors.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks, I think that's more specifically what I meant! Is there anything notable about defective matrices when viewed geometrically?

Comment: I guess the definition is geometric enough: the eigenvectors do not span $\mathbb R^n$. Equivalently, there exists a lower-dimensional subspace (in your example, the $x$-axis) outside of which there are no eigenvectors.

Comment: You might find [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/472915/81360) to be helpful

Comment: I guess I mean maybe in general then - by just having a matrix and observing its transformation, can you "guess" whether its eigenvectors span or do not span ℝ**?