# Triangularization of a non-diagonalisable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, triangularization

Let $\phi$ a linear application and $A$ his matrix such that $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&2&-3\\ 5&1&-5\\ -3&4&0\end{pmatrix}$$

I want to find a inversible matrix $P$ such that there exist a **Upper Triangular** matrix **$D$** with the equation:

$$A=P^{-1} D P$$

This is an exemple that has been built by me to motivate my question. Because this matrix $A$ has only one eigenvector which is $v=(1,1,1)$. That means $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Question 1: How can i find a basis of $P$?

Question 2. How many matrix $D$ are there?

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472915/what-kind-of-matrices-are-non-diagonalizable

Comment: Thank you gregory i will read and try to solve it