# Is $\{0,1\}$ matrix always diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I wonder whether $\{0,1\}$ matrix always diagonalizable? I tried some examples, seems all can be diagonalized. But I seems can not figure out if its algebraic multiplicity is always equal to geometric multiplicity. Could someone help me with it?

Comment: A counterexample is shown in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/472915/42969

Comment: Thank you and I also find one:
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1&1&1&0\\
1&1&1&1\\
\end{matrix}

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A000409 for a statistics for increading n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And how about $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$?  All its eigenvalues are $0$, but it is not similar to $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Here is a simple problem: Take all the $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries from $\{0,1\}$.  Of those $16$ matrices, how many of them are diagonalizable?